# Table usage in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I've a database and log files. I would like to know the least used/unused tables. So, can anyone help me with ways to get details like table usage statistics?

Answer (score 0):

Use percona toolkit for analyzing logs https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/index.html

for slow logs `./pt-query-digest /path/to/slow.log`
or `./pt-table-usage /path/to/log`